# Efeito OnMouseOver

Tags: javascript, eventos-do-mouse

Queria por dois efeito no OnMouseOver para que ao passar o mouse em cima, o texto ficasse de uma cor e o fundo com outra cor. Estou usando este código

```
onmouseover="javascript: this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'"
```

mas neste caso ele só muda o Background, como faço para adicionar outras propriedades???

Daria para criar um estilo em CSS para torna-lo padrão e utilizar onde eu quiser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso dá pra fazer fácil usando apenas o CSS caso prefira.

```css
/* Código para dar o efeito da mudança de cor em 0.5 segundos. */
p {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* código que faz mudar a cor para vermelho e background para verde */
p:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Texto de exemplo</p>
```

Comment: neste caso vc atribuiu ao parâmetro p, porém se eu quiser criar uma classe e atribuir em algumas DIVs por exemplo (não em todas) qual solução? eu tentei fazer **.alteraCor{
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
    alteraCor:hover{
        color: red;
  background-color: green;
    }**

Comment: Funciona também, pode fazer essa classe desta forma que vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar diversos outras propriedades como: `Color`, `Visibility`, `display`, `border-color`, `width`, `height`... entre outros. Sempre que uma propriedade for divida por espaço no css, por exemplo: "`background-color` e `border-color`" em javascript tem que estar juntas, a segunda palavra com a primeira letra maiuscula ficando assim: "`backgroundColor` e `borderColor`".

```html
<form>
  E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'"><br>
   E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.display = 'none'"><br>
   E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.color = 'red'"><br>
  E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.visibility = 'hidden'"><br>
  E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.borderColor = 'red'"><br>
  E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" onmouseover="javascript: this.style.width = '50%'"><br>
  </form
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu queria atribuir 2 eventos no mesmo onmouseover, um que altere o fundo e outro que altere a cor da letra, como o exemplo do Laércio Lopes

Answer (score 0):

Quem quiser mudar somente a cor do texto e não o fundo é so tirar o background e deixar o c minusculo: onmouseover="javascript: this.style.color='red'".